# Kotlin: Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, kotlin

I have an Enum class `RoleType`

```
public enum RoleType {
    SYSTEM_ADMIN, PROJECT_ADMIN, USER;
}
```

In my `User` entity class, I've the following mapping for the enum collection. This is the `Java` code:

```
@JsonProperty
@ElementCollection
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Set<RoleType> roles;
```

I converted this `User` entity class to `Kotlin` and here is the code:

```
@JsonProperty
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "user_id")))
var roles: kotlin.collections.Set<RoleType>? = null
```

After the conversion, hibernate is throwing the following exception:

```
Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity() defined: com.a.b.model.User.roles
```

It was working fine before in Java.

I also tried adding the `targetClass` in `@ElementCollection` like this:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = RoleType::class)
```

but it's also throwing another exception.

```
Fail to process type argument in a generic declaration. Member : com.a.b.model.User#roles Type: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl
ERROR [2017-05-27 04:46:33,123] org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: HCANN000002: An assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate)
! org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Fail to process type argument in a generic declaration. Member : com.a.b.model.User#roles Type: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl
```

**Note**: If i change the modifier of `roles` from `var` to `val`, it's working, but i need this to be a mutable type. I don't understand how the *mutability* of a field is creating issues in hibernate.

**Note**: I'm using Kotlin 1.1.2-2 & Hibernate 5.2 version.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Have you tried changing

```
var roles: Set<RoleType>? = null
```

to

```
var roles: MutableSet<RoleType>? = null
```

If you have a look at the interface definition of `Set`, you'll see it's defined as `public interface Set<out E> : Collection<E>` whereas `MutableSet` is defined as `public interface MutableSet<E> : Set<E>, MutableCollection<E>`

`Set<out E>` 's Java equivalent I believe is `Set<? extends E>` instead of what you were looking for `Set<E>`.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but I was using `List` instead of `MutableList`. This answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: You can also add `@JvmSuppressWildcards` to your `Set<RoleType>` declaration to fix this.

Comment: I have the same problem, and your answer saved my day. Thank you so much.