# Spring Data JPA 'jpaMappingContext' error, IllegalStateException: Expected to be able to resolve a type but got null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA 5.0.4 and am getting this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'myRepository': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property
>   'mappingContext'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected
>   to be able to resolve a type but got null! This usually stems from
>   types implementing raw Map or Collection interfaces! at...

This is my `myRepository` bean:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEvent, Long> {

    List<MyEvent> findAll();

    MyEvent save(MyEvent persisted);

    Optional<MyEvent> findById(Long id);

    Optional<MyEvent> findByMyEventId(long id);

    List<MyEvent> findByCurrentActivityTypeCd(BigDecimal id);

    List<MyEvent> findByCity(String city);
}
```

Here is how I scan the beans in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:spring-configured />
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

   <tx:annotation-driven />

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.service, com.my.repository" />
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it was because my entity has an attribute of type `Map`. Just change it for `HashMap` or similar.

Comment: if someone else is search the answer for kotlin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44213463/5749192

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exactly problem and I solve it setting `@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.mypackage.entity"})`

Comment: Can you specify where exactly you added this annotation? On the Datasource configuration class? Or the Spring Application main class?