# Erasure ManyToOne List type in Kotlin Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin

I'm trying create a simples ManyToOne relation in Springs

```
// City.kt
package com.example.helpme.entity

import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.*

@Entity
data class City(
    @Id id: Int,
    var name: String,
    @ManyToOne(optional = false) state: State
)
```

```
// State.kt
package com.example.helpme.entity

import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.*

@Entity
data class State(
    @Id id: Int,
    var name: String,
    @OneToMany cities: Set<City> = emptySet(),
)
```

But Intelij Idea tell me that ['One To Many' attribute value type should not be '? extends City'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXX03.png)

And when I'm trying run I get

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity() defined: com.example.helpme.entity.State.products`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin: Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213074/kotlin-collection-has-neither-generic-type-or-onetomany-targetentity)

Answer (score 2):

Change `Set` to `MutableSet` works to me

```
// State.kt
package com.example.helpme.entity

import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.*

@Entity
data class State(
    @Id id: Int,
    var name: String,
    @OneToMany cities: MutableSet<City> = mutableSetOf(),
)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come up with this solution? I would've been stuck if I didn't find this